# Merge Genymotion .vmdk disks into one?

Tags: android, virtualbox, vmware, genymotion

I have a Genymotion Android emulator that I want to export from Virtualbox for use inside a different virtualization platform that requires a single .vmdk per VM. Unfortunately, when I export my Genymotion emulator it creates 3 separate .vmdk files from the following disks: a 1.03GB android_system_disk.vmdk (IDE primary master), a 5.51GB android_data_disk.vmdk (IDE primary slave), and an 8.00GB sdcard.vdi (IDE secondary master). Does anyone know if there is an easy way to merge all 3 files into a single .vmdk in such a way that the emulator will still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualBox to export your appiliance. that will save alle your files in `*.ova` file. after that you can import your `.ova` file to VirtualBox